# how to create a directory with suffix .dat and also add suffix to all the files in that directory to .dat

Tags: bash, shell

I want to create a directory that suffixes `.dat`.

I want to write a shell script that creates a directory with the same name which I will give on the command line.

Example:

I have created a directory `source_dir` and in this directory, I have two files i.e
`file1.txt file2.sh`

When I run the `.sh` file

`bash demo.sh source_dir`

So the shell script in demo.sh should take care of the below things:

1. Creates a directory with the same name but add a suffix to it i.e `.dat`
2. Move all the files from `source_dir` to `source_dir.dat` and also add a suffix to all the files to `file1.txt.dat file2.sh.dat`

My attempt:

In a shell script how I will be able to create a directory with the same name as given on the command line?

To suffix the file names that we can achieve using

`for file in source_dir.bak/*; do mv -- "$file" "$file.bak"; done`

Comment: The first parameter you pass can be referred to with `$1`. So just `mkdir -p "$1.dat"` (the `-p` option of `mkdir` avoids getting an error if the directory exists already; it also allows to create a hierarchy of directories at once, e.g. `bash demo.sh dir1/dir2/source_dir`). Note that the questions you ask are so basic `bash` questions that you should seriously consider reading a `bash` quick starter instead of building your script pieces after pieces from SO answers.

Comment: @RenaudPacalet Sure. But one thing when I am running ```bash demo.sh source_dir``` . My sh file contains below code:
``` mkdir -p "$1.bak"                                                                                                       mv x.txt sample.txt big.sh emp.dat $1.bak                                                                               for file in $1.bak/*; do mv -- $"file" "$file.bak"; done ``` but it is throwing error mv: cannot stat No such file or directory

Comment: Prefer copy-pasting instead of typing, you'll avoid typos: `mv -- $"file" "$file.bak";` is wrong, it's `mv -- "$file" "$file.bak";`. Again, if you knew the very basics of `bash`, it would take you half a second to spot such errors.